# angularjs - confusion about nested named views with angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs

Using `angular-ui-router`, an external routing plugin for `angular` found [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), I am attempting to understand how the nested named views work. I got the initial demos working fine, but tried to make some modifications, like this;

```
$stateProvider
   .state('default', {
      url: "/default",
      views: {
         "viewA" : { templateUrl: "angular/partials/default.A.html" },
         "viewB" : { templateUrl: "angular/partials/default.B.html" }
      }
   })
   .state('state1.list', {
      url: "/state1list",
      views: {
         "viewAList" : { 
            templateUrl: "angular/partials/state1.list.html",
            controller: function($scope) {
               $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
            }
         }
      }
   });
```

The idea is that I am setting the list contents to a `named view` that is nested inside of the `default.A.html` file.

## Error

The error message I receive is this;

> Error: Could not resolve 'state1.list' from state 'default'

## HTML

The html looks like this;

## index.html

```
<div ui-view="viewA"></div>
<div ui-view="viewB"></div>
```

## angular/partials/default.A.html

```
<h1>Default.A.HTML</h1>
<hr />
<a ui-sref="state1.list">Show List</a>
<div ui-view="viewAList"></div>
```

## angular/partials/state1.list.html

```
<h3>List of State 1 Items</h3>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item }}</li>
</ul>
```

## angular/partials/default.B.html

```
<h1>Default.B.HTML</h1>
<hr />
```

Comment: After further testing, it seems that the route name might have been the issue. When I changed the route to `default.list`, it worked. Can anyone confirm/elaborate on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you supply state1.list, the 'state1' state is considered to be the parent of the 'state1.list' state. But you don't have a state named 'state1'. Once you change it to 'default.list', the inferred parent is 'default', which works because you do have a 'default' state. If you created a new state named 'state1' and then another one named 'state1.list' then that would work as well.

> Naming Your States (From https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views)
>
> No two states can have the same name. When using dot notation the
>   parent is inferred if it is not explicitly provided, but this doesn't
>   change the state name. When not using dot notation, the parent must be
>   explicitly provided, but you still cannot name any two states the
>   same, for example you can't have two different states named "edit"
>   even if they have different parents.

Comment: An important detail that I wish I had found on the docs. Thank you so much for clarifying.